# skip current iteration

Tags: php, loops

I have a php array `$numbers = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)`

if I am looping over it using a foreach `foreach($numbers as $number)`

and have an if statement `if($number == 4)`

what would the line of code be after that that would skip anything after that line and start the loop at 5? break, return, exit?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You are looking for the [continue](http://php.net/continue) statement. Also useful is [break](http://php.net/break) which will exit the loop completely. Both statements work with all variations of loop, ie. `for`, `foreach` and `while`.

```
$numbers = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 );
foreach( $numbers as $number ) {
    if ( $number == 4 ) { continue; }
    // ... snip
}
```

Comment: ah continue, Thank's, I had tried all my above mentioned options. Will accept asap

Comment: Isn't `continue` considered a bad coding practice? For the same reasons as `goto`...

Comment: Not really. Jumps aren't bad. `goto` as implemented in languages that actually had it let you jump to literally anywhere in the application, that's what was bad. Function calls, conditional statements, anything that introduces branching, they all use jumps and that's ok. `continue` has a single well defined use case. It's fine. If anything `break` is worse.

Comment: The bad practice is to set wrong names to statements such as this... `continue` here actually means `skip`.

Answer (score 28):

```
continue;
```

Continue will tell it to skip the current iteration block, but continue on with the rest of the loop. Works in all scenerios (for, while, etc.)

Comment: *"skip the current iteration block, but continue on with the rest of the loop"* 
 Thanks, a very clear way to express it.

Answer (score 15):

Break; will stop the loop and make compiler out side the loop. while continue; will just skip current one and go to next cycle.
like:

```
$i = 0;
while ($i++)
{
    if ($i == 3)
    {
        continue;
    }
    if ($i == 5)
    {
        break;
    }
    echo $i . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
4
6 <- this won't happen
```

Comment: but it will break the entire loop dont just skip the current iteration

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are looking for continue statement. Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php

dinel